# R png function not working when adding "{filename}.png" extension

Tags: r

I am trying to save a plot in png format. I am using the following code:

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars)+
  geom_point(aes(x = hp, y = mpg))

png(filename = 'filename.png')
p
dev.off()
```

However, when I run without the file extension, it works:

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars)+
  geom_point(aes(x = hp, y = mpg))

png(filename = 'filename')
p
dev.off()
```

The following error is raised:

```
Error in png(filename = "filename.png") : 
  não é possível iniciar dispositivo png()
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In png(filename = "filename.png") :
  unable to open file 'filename.png' for writing
2: In png(filename = "filename.png") : opening device failed
```

The error is independent if I use `png()`, `jpeg()` or `ggsave()` functions.

**UPDATE:**

- I already tried to clear my workspace, restarted the computer, and tried different folders with different access scopes. It only works if I don't use the *.png, *.jpeg or *.pdf extensions.
- It works for *.svg extensions.
- If I try to rename the file to add the .png extension, it does not work due to "access denied". But if I rename to add .svg extension, it works and converts the file to .svg.

Thanks all in advance :)

Comment: Where is `png()` from (which package)?

Comment: What OS are you using? Was a previously saved file of the same name open when you tried to save again?

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** I got it:
There must be some masking or kind of overlapping between different packages with png() function. When using **`grDevices` package** it works in contrast to `png()` function from **`png` package**:

```
library(grDevices)
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars)+
  geom_point(aes(x = hp, y = mpg))

grDevices::png(filename = 'filename7.png')
p
dev.off()
```

**First answer:**
Replace `filename` by `file`: Then it should work:

This is a good question. I can't figure out why this happens, because the argument is `filename`.

```
library(png)
library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(mtcars)+
  geom_point(aes(x = hp, y = mpg))

png(file = 'filename.png')
#or
png('filename.png')

p
dev.off()
```

Comment: The error persists with this setup. For the record, I am using Windows 10 x64, and the function png() is loaded by package grDevices.

The code I've tried:

grDevices::png('filename.png')
p
dev.off()

Comment: Hmmmh. Please Clear your workspace and restart all. ?!

Comment: Already done that, without success...

 *.svg works, though.